# Returning a value to the calling thread

Tags: php, multithreading

I'm trying to use pthreads in PHP in an attempt to speed up a series of calculations that at the moment max out one CPU core for several seconds. I have split the calculations into a number of ranges and am running each range in the parent thread:

```
    $threads = array();
    foreach($cp as $c) {
        $threads[$c] = new ThreadedMatcher($params);
        $threads[$c]->start();
    }
```

I then want to `array_merge` the arrays created in each child thread (for each range) in the parent thread to get a value over the whole data set.

I gather that I need to use `join()` in the parent thread to wait for a thread to finish but how do I actually get a value out of the child thread into the parent thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

This will split the Payload according to your available cores, looping across batches, not to exceed the available Cpus maximum threads.
I am using this very simple principle over many other Pthreads possibilities I have tested. Simplest and most efficient one for me so far.

Works flawlessly with xenons servers and 80 available Cpus threads over 100M iterations for hours.

```
$Pay_Load=array(
array('id'=>$id,'query'=>$query1,'param'=>$param1),
array('id'=>$id,'query'=>$query2,'param'=>$param2),
/*... can be hundreds...just an example...*/
)

$Nb_of_Cpus=4;
$Nb_of_threads=$Nb_of_Cpus*2;
$Batch_Works=array_chunk($Pay_Load,$Nb_of_threads);

$threads = [];
$results = array();

foreach ($Batch_Works as $batch) {
    foreach ($batch as $key => $params) {
        $threads[$key] = new ThreadedMatcher($params);
        $threads[$key]->start();
    }
    foreach ($batch as $key => $params) {
        $threads[$key]->join();
        $returned_result=$threads[$key]->result;
        $returned_id=$threads[$key]->id;
        $result=array('id'=>$returned_id,'result'=>$returned_result);
        array_push($results, result);    
    }
}
/* all returned results are now in the same array */
/* with the original Payload id as an example here */
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: How are these lines getting data from the ThreadedMatcher?         $returned_result=$threads[$key]->result;
        $returned_id=$threads[$key]->id;

Comment: Yes. Set them as public in class.

Comment: $this->id. $this->result. At the end of the run class.

Comment: PHP arrays are passed by value. This mean that the entire array will have to be (re)allocated in the thread and deallocated on it's join, which would decrease considerably the performance you seek when dealing with threads. Consider passing the array as reference instead.

Answer (score 2):

The complete class:

```
class ThreadedMatcher extends Thread {

private $query;
private $param;
public $result;
public $id;


public function __construct($params) {

    $this->query = $params['query'];
    $this->param = $params['param'];
    $this->id= $params['id'];

}

public function run() {

    /* do some stuff*/
    echo ($this->query);
    echo ($this->param);

    $this->result = rand(100, 200);
}
}

$Pay_Load=array(
array('id'=>$id,'query'=>$query1,'param'=>$param1),
array('id'=>$id,'query'=>$query2,'param'=>$param2),
/*... can be hundreds...just an example...*/
)

$Nb_of_Cpus=4;
$Nb_of_threads=$Nb_of_Cpus*2;
$Batch_Works=array_chunk($Pay_Load,$Nb_of_threads);

$threads = [];
$results = array();

foreach ($Batch_Works as $batch) {
    foreach ($batch as $key => $params) {
        $threads[$key] = new ThreadedMatcher($params);
        $threads[$key]->start();
    }
    foreach ($batch as $key => $params) {
        $threads[$key]->join();
        $returned_result=$threads[$key]->result;
        $returned_id=$threads[$key]->id;
        $result=array($returned_id=>$returned_result);
        array_push($results, result);    
    }
}
/* all returned results are now in the same array */
/* with the original Payload id as an example here */

var_dump($results);

$results =(
1=>103,
2=>234,
3=>345,
4=>123)
```

Comment: The secret of this process is , while you prepare your payload array, is to determine the number of iterations that will be computed for each workers. Sort them properly and have your Batch_Works chunked accordingly.